# Find the General Solution to $x^3y''' + 2x^2y'' - xy' + y = \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

> Find the general solution to 
>   $$
> x^3y''' + 2x^2y'' - xy' + y = \frac{1}{x}
> $$

The problem is that I've only dealt with power series with $g(t)=0$, not an actual function. I have the solution available 
$$
c_1x^{-1} + c_2x + c_3x\ln x + \frac{\ln x}{4x}
$$ 
but I have no idea how to attempt to solve this equation. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

**Step 1**  Solving the homogeneous problem with the ansatz $y = x^\alpha$.

**Step 2**  Use the reduction of order to obtain a third homogeneous solution.

**Step 3**  Solve for a particular solution using higher-order variation of parameter.